# Passing list of json object to controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an array of json to my controller but struggling with it.

Below is the code

**Javascript code**

```
var options = {
                    'url': "Collection.mvc/ReorderAndDeleteTitles",
                    'data': "dids=1&rTitles=" + ReorderGridData(),
                    'type': "POST",
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'traditional': true,
                    'killOverlays': false,
                    'showloader': false,
                    'onSuccess': function (data) {

                    },
                    'onError': function (data) {
                        ShowAjaxError(data);
                        $().killOverlays();
                    }
                };
                $().ajaxCall(options);//used for making ajax calls

//returns the titleID and its new order
function ReorderGridData() {
    var ssIds = [];
    $('table.resultsTable').find('tbody tr.updated').each(function (index) {
        var titleId = $(this).find('td.th_collectionTitleId').attr('title');
        var newOrder = $(this).find('input.js-sortText').val();
        ssIds.push({ Records: { Id: titleId, NewOrder: newOrder} });
    });

    return ssIds;
}
```

**Controller code**

```
public class TitleReorder
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string NewOrder { get; set; }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public void ReorderAndDeleteTitles(string dids, List<TitleReorder> rTitles)
        {

        }
```

When i debug i get rTitles param as null

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JSON request to send complex javascript literals to controller actions. Take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx).

Comment: m afraid i cannot use any more plugins in my project.

Comment: @Amit, which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: i m using mvc3 with jquery 1.4+

Comment: @Amit, oh then you don't need any plugins. ASP.NET MVC 3 has a built-in JsonValueProviderFactory allowing you to parse JSON requests. Just read the blog post I have linked to.

Comment: but your blog still make use of that plugin?

Comment: @Amit, what plugin are you talking about? The blog post says that if you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you do not need to download the `JsonValueProviderFactory` since it is built-in. Look at the part of the blog post which sends the ajax request using $.ajax and setting the contentType to application/json.

Comment: Ok, its working for me now, i passed the json as string and in my controller  used JavaScriptSerializer  to reserialize it and it worked. Thanks